# Submitting Form Via Javascript, form defined in external PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit

I have a form which is injected into the page body via php. I have a button which triggers a javascript validation function, and at the end it should submit the form but it doesn't seem to want to submit.

I'm using the function call:

```
document.myform.submit();
```

The script definitely reaches this function call, as I have a debug alert() message pop up successfully. Its located in a validate&submit function which is defined after a jquery  $(document).ready() function.

I've checked all the obvious things like form tags opened/closed properly, form name correct etc but I can't seem to work out the problem.

Any ideas? I haven't submitted the whole file as its cluttered with other stuff, but I can if needed.

Many Thanks,
Oliver

Heres the html source after php has done its thing: http://pastebin.com/2EaucEar

Comment: Can't do much without seeing your code.

Comment: Judging by the colour coding of the source you have posted there appears to be some HTML errors - lack of spaces between element attributes, which could be tripping up the processing of the DOM correctly.

Comment: Do your alert also reaches the else statement where the form will submit? Ever try to use firebug or chrome developer tools. Have a try to see if you encounter a javascript error.

Comment: The alert in the final else statement of the EditFormSubmit() function does fire correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found it!**

I'm using a button which is made to look like a normal link, but not using any of the button features. So it might as well be a link. The name of the button was *name='submit'* which made perfect sense to me, but I made sure it wasn't a submit button by setting the *type='button'*.

It seems submit is a keyword, and cast the button as a submit or something. Not entirely sure, but changing the button name (which I don't refer to in the rest of the code) to something else fixed the problem.

Thanks for your help guys. You helped me narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of tinkering. When I finally got to the point where your submit line is called, I got a javascript error. Since you are using jQuery, try using the following:

```
 $('#editForm').submit();
```

If it helps any, here is the jsFiddle that I was using to tinker around with.

http://jsfiddle.net/CkvLj/7/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: I tried using a jquery selector earlier (which is why the form has an id). As 'w3d' mentioned, the syntnax highlighting went abit funny around the form, so I made sure there were spaces between all the attributes but still no luck.   

So there is nothing wrong with my submit/validation approach, but there must be a syntax error muddled in there somewhere you think?

Comment: Here is the php function used to spit out the form into the main index file http://pastebin.com/hPnZQgTs

Comment: I did notice that you are missing a semicolon on the '&middot;' character.

Comment: This is the javascript error I see 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function' in chrome.