# JavaScript: formname.submit(); not working

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following form:

```
<form id="vintro-upload-form" action="{url}?nexturl={nextUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="file" type="file"/>
<input name="token" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input value="Upload Video File" type="button" name="submit" onClick="checkFile()" class="button" />
</form>
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script>
function checkFile(){
 var fileVal = document.forms["vintro-upload-form"].elements['file'].value;
 //RegEx for valid file name and extensions.
 if(fileVal != ""){vintro-upload-form.submit();} 
 else {alert('Please select the Video file.');}
}
</script>
```

What works? The fileVal assignment is good.  Submit isn't working, when I checked the debugger, it is saying: "vintro is undefined."

What have I tried?
The following examples and code:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp
- http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml
- document.vintro-upload-form.submit();
- document.forms["vintro-upload-form"].submit();
- document.getElementById("vintro-upload-form").submit();
- changed the dashes/hyphens to underscores

All to no success.  There is some jQuery (in another .js file) going on with this form as well, and it functions properly with the hyphenated name.

Why is the submit call not working?

EDIT:
I have tried using `document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit();` as suggested in the answers to this question, however, this is still failing.  My (Firefox) debugger is saying that it is not a function.  Chrome's debugger explained a little bit more: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function" (I'm going to Google this in the meantime.)

Since I have less than 100 reputation:
Ok, so it turns out, I was asking the wrong question.

Here's the answer I found:
[Submitting Form Via Javascript, form defined in external PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446420/submitting-form-via-javascript-form-defined-in-external-php-file)

Check the accepted answer as well.

Comment: Small tip: the W3schools site is seen by many as giving low-quality information on JavaScript, the Mozilla docs are seen as one of the better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Comment: Another tip to more easily let other people take a look at your JavaScript problem: http://JSFiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This JavaScript:

`document.forms["vintro-upload-form"].elements['file'].value`

is looking for the NAME attribute of the form tag:

`document.forms[{form_name}].elements[{field_name}].value`

You just have an ID. Copy the value of the ID to a NAME and you're done.

However, document.getElementById() is the preferred, modern way of doing this with plain JavaScript.

**HOWEVER: You can't have a submit / button named "submit".**

When you do and you call the JavaScript submit() function, you get a conflict.

Comment: I'm still new to web development, and this seems like something obvious, so I'll know to look for it in the future.  Additionally, this is preexisting code I didn't write myself that I'm working with now.

Comment: No worries. I'm constantly refactoring legacy code. Sometimes you can update it to use the latest and greatest, but sometimes you have to stay old school.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need:`document.getElementById('nameofform').submit()` is easier to find elements by its id than for the name.

Other way is to get elements by name, you can do it with `document.getElementsByName('nameofform')`...But that returns an array so you need to iterate that array to find which of those forms is needed to be uploaded. So, I think you should use the id.

Comment: Debugger: (X) document.getElementById("vintro-upload-form").submit is not a function [next line] document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit();  [then it gives me the line number]  :: this didn't work either, any other ideas? ::

Comment: Are you sure the Id of that form is 'vintro-upload-form'? and you need to call submit method with '()' I mean: `document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit()`

And for the form id is someting like: `<form id='vintro-upload-form'><!--And here every fields needed for the form--></form>`

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form')` say under the debugger?  Is it able to find the element at all?

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm not sure what you mean by "under the debugger," but if you look at the my first comment on this answer, that is what I'm seeing.  When I mouse over the document.forms["..."].elements['file'].value, I can see the form name; but when I mouse over the form name in the getElementById call, I get nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your form contains characters that cannot be used in a JavaScript identifier (dashes). Use `document.getElementById('vintro-upload-form').submit();` instead.

Comment: That's the convention, but is not a must. However I think is a good practice to follow the conventions, more when your projects need more than one person.